# How to implement Face Recognition with OpenCV and Xamarin

Tags: python, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a face recognition program built with **python OpenCV**. It detects images from a camera input and recognizes the image of a particular user from a list of recognized users (over 1000).

Is there any way that this can be integrated to a mobile app developed using **Xamarin.Forms** ?

What can be done to implement this on mobile device?

Comment: You could translate your python to something that can run on the device, such as C#. You could use EmguCV or similar. But "Is there a better way to do this?" is a very broad question, which can't be answered with a single concise answer. Hence, not a great fit for Stack Overflows QA style.

Comment: @Cheesebaron My app will be able to recognize a user from a list of users like 4000 and if implemented on the device, it will increase app size.

Comment: Well then you are probably better off with a Web Service. Xamarin.Forms does not put any limitation to this problem. Xamarin.Forms is a UI abstraction layer and has nothing to do with face detection.

Comment: @Cheesebaron So my thinking is to capture a set of images from user (say 10) and upload it to the web-service for comparison. But it might be a slow process since images are uploaded. Any suggestion?